# How to use awrapbootstrap (made with twitter bootstrap) themes with Middleman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, middleman

The website wrapbootstrap.com sells Twitter Bootstrap themes. The theme I purchased was built on Middleman and my hope was to get it live and running in Middleman before trying to get it running on rails. I contacted the seller multiple times through the site without an answer so I am turning to SO for help.

Using a Vagrant VM, I am able to get Middleman up and running with the "MIDDLEMAN IS WATCHING" base page when I go to localhost:8886 (My vagrantfile is set up to redirect port 8000 to 8886 on my local host).

With Middleman working, I move on to getting the wrapbootstrap theme up and running:

1. Copy the wrapboostrap files to a new project folder (file are temporarily here: https://github.com/badhashsolution/Wrapboostrap_question ).
2. $ rvm gemset create wrap_project
3. $ rvm gemset use wrap_project
4. $ bundle install
5. $ bundle exec middleman server --port=8000 (my vagrant file is set up to use port 8000 and redirect it to localhost:8886)
6. When I go to localhost:8886, which worked with a base install of middleman, I now have the message: "**File Not Found
   /pages/dashboard/dashboard.html**"
7. Some of research I did on the web suggested that this would be solved by deleting the gemlock file and rerunning bundle install, but this does not fix the issue
8. Also, as you can see from the files on github, there is a pages/dashboard/dashboard.html file

Comment: Just spent the last half hour unpicking your problem. There is many things wrong with this theme :(. I would ask for your money back. (eg its not a simple problem you're trying to solve).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and helping me know I'm not crazy! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this in a couple ways.

1. It is the Core Admin theme from Wrapbootstrap and it comes with a
   Bootstrap 3.0 and a Bootstrap 2.0 version.
2. I switched to the Bootstrap 2.0 version then deleted the gemlock
       file and re-ran bundle install
3. After this the file worked just fine on "localhost:8886/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html"  Note that my Vagrant VM is pointing to port 8886